# Make SKU mandatory in Woocommerce before publishing a product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, sku

I would like to know if there is any way to make the SKU field required, before publishing a new product. Otherwise, if there is no SKU, to be able to save the product only as a draft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can simply use this very simple code snippet to display an error message when the SKU field is empty when trying to save a the product *(works for products and variations too)*.

If the product with an empty SKU is published, it will be saved as "DRAFT".

The code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'mandatory_product_sku');
add_action('woocommerce_admin_process_variation_object', 'mandatory_product_sku');
function mandatory_product_sku( $product ) {
    if( ! $product->get_sku( 'edit' ) ) {
        $message = __( 'Caution! The SKU field is required.', 'woocommerce' );
        
        if( $product->get_status('edit') === 'publish' ) {
            $product->set_status('draft');
            $message .= ' ' . __('Product has been saved as "DRAFT".', 'woocommerce' );
        }
        WC_Admin_Meta_Boxes::add_error( $message );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I tested on two different websites, with two different themes, and it doesn't display any error message. The new product can be published as always.

"Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme)." - as you said.

Comment: Thanks so much, it's working perfectly fine.